# The special case of NTRUEncrypt when N = q

Tags: lattice-crypto, ntru

I've found this task in the "**Introduction Mathematical Cryptography by Jeffrey Hoffstein**":

*The guidelines for choosing NTRUEncrypt public parameters (N, p, q, d) in-clude the assumption that gcd(N, q) = 1. Suppose instead that Alice takes q = N ,
where as always, N is an odd prime.*

*(a) Make a change of variables x = y + 1 in the ring Z[x]/(xN − 1), and show that
the NTRU lattice takes a simpler form.*

*(b) Can you find an efficient way to break NTRU in the case that q = N that does
involve lattice reduction? (This appears to be an open problem.)*

I have no idea where to start. I didn't find any valuable information on the net. Can anyone offer me literature that explores this particular problem?(Or maybe the step with the change of variables x = y + 1)

Comment: What is $(y + 1)^q \bmod q$?

Comment: 1+y^q, I guess. Thanks!